# URLStreamHandler for JNDI in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, osgi, jndi

How can I create an URLStreamHandler for JNDI in tomcat 8?
Is there any available URLStreamHandler for JNDI in tomcat 8?

In tomcat 7 there were some classes in the org.apache.naming.resources to get this done. But in tomcat 8 these classes are no longer exist.

In tomcat 8 I tried

```
URLStreamHandler urlStreamHandler = `TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstance().createURLStreamHandler("jndi");`
```

But this return null

In tomcat 7

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(URLConstants.URL_HANDLER_PROTOCOL, "jndi");
final URLStreamHandler handler = new DirContextURLStreamHandler();

bundleContext.registerService(URLStreamHandlerService.class.getName(),
    new AbstractURLStreamHandlerService() {
        private final static String EMPTY_STRING = "";
        public URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
            return new URL(u, EMPTY_STRING, handler).openConnection();
        }
    }, properties);
```

Comment: There's one already built in, but you don't need to know about it. Just lookup the resource and see what you get. It's either a URL with a handler already attached, or an input stream, I forget which.

Comment: @EJP what I actually want to do is register an URLStreamHandler for JNDi in the OSGI bundle.

Comment: @EJP I updated the question with what I have tried in tomcat8. But that return null

Comment: Actually what you want to do is read an input stream from a JNDI resource, and I've told you you can already do it.

Comment: @EJP I want to register a service in OSGi bundle. So I can refer that service later. Please see the update. Sorry for any inconveneance